# Concurrent processing of dataset

Tags: java, concurrency

I've got the following scenario:

There are two SQL-databases. I have to read a bunch of rows from the first DB, extract an XML field from a row, transform it with XSLT and some other logic, and insert it into the second DB.
XSLT transformation is rather expensive (300 ms per row approximately), and I assume that concurrent processing of this transformation would speed up my migration.

The question is: how to manage the read process from the first DB? To read all rows into collection as a bulk and following concurrent processing looks like bad idea. Is there some kind of pattern here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the perfect candidate for [Spring batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/).

You'll be able to define readers for reading from the DB, a processor to do the XSLT transform and parallelize the process.  It also provides support for reading in chunks so you don't have to have the whole dataset in memory.

Comment: Thanks again, I used Spring Batch, and it works great. I've published the solution [here](https://github.com/vic0nt/spring-batch-multithreaded)